# How does an AsyncServerRequestHandler set response headers?

Tags: java, http2

When using the Apache httpcore 5 for java how does the handle() method in an AsyncServerRequestHandler add headers to the response?

There are a couple of examples at https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.0.x/examples.html such as https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.0.x/httpcore5-h2/examples/org/apache/hc/core5/http/examples/Http2FileServerExample.java , but they are somewhat dense.

Under the old httpcore <= 4 you would do something like

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
```

but it is unclear which of the MANY layers of indirection that httpcore 5 uses is the layer with access to the response headers, and which object has the method corresponding to setHeader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `HttpResponse` into the constructor of `BasicResponseProducer`.

So for example in the [Http2FileServerExample](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-5.0.x/httpcore5-h2/examples/org/apache/hc/core5/http/examples/Http2FileServerExample.java) in the question:

```
responseTrigger.submitResponse(new BasicResponseProducer(
                HttpStatus.SC_OK, new FileEntityProducer(file, contentType)));
```

can become:

```
BasicHttpResponse response = new BasicHttpResponse(HttpStatus.SC_OK);
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
responseTrigger.submitResponse(new BasicResponseProducer(
                response, new FileEntityProducer(file, contentType)));
```